# Why does my code keep repeating the question prompt instead of progressing to the conditional statements?

Tags: python, function, while-loop, conditional-statements

When I run my code it keeps iterating thought the beginning of the while loop even when the inputs match the conditional statements. when I input "y" it repeats the question prompt same with input "l" or by inputting "e"

```
intro = "Welcome to the leap year Calculator\n"
print(intro)
leapyear = True
def leap_year_calc():
    test= input("What year are you checking? ")
    year = int(test)
    if ((year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0)) or (year % 400 == 0):
       prompt = str(year) + " Is a leap year"
       print (prompt)
       return leapyear == True
    else:
       prompt = str(year) + " Isn't a leap year"
       print (prompt)
       return leapyear == True
def leap_year_list():
    leap_years = []
    for i in range(4001):
        if i >= 1752: #this was the 1st leap year in th Gregorian calender
            if ((i % 4 == 0) and (i % 100 != 0)) or (i % 400 == 0):
                leap_years.append(i)
        else:
           pass
    print(leap_years)
    return leap_years

while leapyear != False:
     question = input("Do you want to know if a year is a leap year(type 'y'), \nor see a list of leap years(type 'l') or exit (type 'e'? ").lower
     if question == 'y':
        leap_year_calc()
     elif question == 'l':
        leap_year_list()
     else:
        leapyear == False

#leap_year_calc()
#leap_year_list()
```

Comment: Please use 4-space indentation. It help to distinguish several blocks of code

Comment: There are a lot of `else` statements you could try removing.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the () in the lower function:

```
question = input("Do you want to know if a year is a leap year(type 'y'), \nor see a list of leap years(type 'l') or exit (type 'e'? ").lower()
```

Comment: that wouldn't be the reason for their problem, allthough this might raise and Exception

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:

```
while leapyear != False:
      question = input("Do you want to know if a year is a leap year(type 'y'), \nor see a list of leap years(type 'l') or exit (type 'e'? ").lower
      if question == 'y':
        leap_year_calc()
      elif question == 'l':
        leap_year_list()
```

Do:

```
while leapyear:
      question = input("Do you want to know if a year is a leap year(type 'y'), \nor see a list of leap years(type 'l') or exit (type 'e'? ").lower
      if question == 'y':
        leap_year_calc()
      elif question == 'l':
        leap_year_list()
      else:
        leapyear = False
```

Comment: You missed parenthesis after `.lower` it should be `.lower()`